# Why does this compile: string = int

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stdstring

Suppose the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int func() { return 2; }

int main()
{
   std::string str("str");
   str = func();
   std::cout << "Acquired value: '" << str << "'" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Why does the line `str = func();` compile without warning of a type mismatch?

I'm using compiler gcc v. 4.7.1 with the -std=c++11 flag set.

Output:

`Acquired value: ''`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `std::string` class includes an overloaded `operator=` that accepts a `char` value. Since `char` is an integer type, `int` is implicitly convertible to `char`.

The value being assigned to `str` isn't an empty string; it's a string of length 1 whose single character has the value 2 (Ctrl-B).

Try feeding your program's output to `cat -v` or `hexdump`.

```
$ ./c | cat -v
Acquired value: '^B'
```

Comment: and this `int -> char` conversion is allowed because of backward compatibility with C,  `std::string` class has `string& operator= (char c);` overloaded assignment operator.

Comment: I just find this weird. It also blew up a project at work after a copy/paste error. It would be nice if the compiler at least warned of implicit type conversion or type mismatch...

Comment: If C++ compilers warned about implicit conversions, you'd be buried in warning messages. `long n = 42;` has an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, for example. The fact that `char` is an integer type is, I suppose, the real problem; as Destructor says, that's inherited from C.

Comment: @KeithThompson: what about `-Wall` & `-Wconversion` ? They can be useful here to turn on.

Comment: @Destructor: `g++ -Wconversion` gives `warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]`. (Which isn't actually correct, though it could be on a system where `char` is unsigned and `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, which requires `CHAR_BIT > 8`.)